# Does electrum wallet "sit on top of" bitcoin-cli?

Tags: electrum, bitcoin-cli

Does electrum wallet "sit on top of" bitcoin-cli? Or is it an abstraction of some other software?
I have already learned that Electrum's gui [is not
a wrap around their cli](https://github.com/spesmilo/electrum/issues/5791) and there are some things that you can do in its gui, like bumping fees, that you cannot from their cli.
Does their core library utilize `bitcoin-cli` under the hood?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No - electrum does not use `bitcoin-cli` under the hood. Although they use it in [their tests](https://github.com/spesmilo/electrum/search?q=bitcoin-cli). `bitcoin-cli` is part of `bitcoind` *(bitcoin core)*. You can find electrums implementation of the wallet [here](https://github.com/spesmilo/electrum/blob/master/electrum/wallet.py).